Telebot ошибка new_chat_members | PYTHON
я столкнулся с проблемой, которая возникает как в aiogram, так и в telebot. Боты не регистрируют новых пользователей чата, если нет определённого сообщения о входе. Такое сообщение отсутствует в чатах, где количество участников составляет примерно 2000 человек и более.
Я имею в виду сообщения типа "Пользователь теперь в группе".

Оно отображается для всех участников чата только в чатах с небольшим количеством пользователей, а в чатах с большим количеством пользователей оно отображается только для того, кто зашёл.
Сразу скажу: бот работает, но только когда есть соответствующее сообщение от системы. Я выдал боту администратора и установил /setprivacy на "выключено".
Пример кода:
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['new_chat_members'])
def welcome_new_members(message):
    print("[de")
    print(f"Received new member: {message.new_chat_members[0].id}")


Об этом давно известно. И это не проблема aiogram или telebot, просто телеграм не присылает такие сообщения

@causonq а как тогда боты детектят что новый пользователь зашел

Думаю, что нужно смотреть в сторону ChatMemberUpdated. Сам, правда, не пробовал, использую сервисные сообщения. Но нужно разобраться, да
